# Передача out маркера

Tags: c++, usb

Спецификация пакетов usb твердит о передаче маркера!
С устройством работаю как с файлом то есть ReadFile WriteFile.
Как отправить устройству  Маркер Out для изохронной передачи ?

Comment: Этим занимается железо/драйвер/ОС, вам достаточно только писать в файл. Поменять режим работы, например с bulk на изохронный нельзя - само устройство сообщает дескрипторами, какие у неё конечные точки и в каких режимах они работают. Особый вариант - если устройство имеет несколько конечных точек с разными режимами передачи и позволяет выбор на уровне пользователя, тогда смотрите в описании к нему, каким образом посылать данные в конкретную конечную точку (это может быть другое логическое USB устройство, либо специальные IO control команды).